# While clicking label event is fired twice in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

This is HTML code:

```
<label for="like" ng-click="copyRec()">
    <input type="checkbox" id="like" value="val"/>
    Click
</label>
```

In my Angular controller:

```
$scope.copyRec = function() {
    console.log("inside");
};
```

While clicked its firing twice. Can anyone help me out in solving this?

Comment: Shouldn't your click be on the Checkbox?

Comment: Label triggers the checkbox so i think directly clicking on the label is actually clicking the checkbox. Try adding some text befoe the checkbox and then try.

Comment: click can be on checkbox or label it should call once copyRec @Hanlet

Comment: yeah ! I tried as you mentioned but it is firing twice @hunzaboy

Comment: When you place it in the label and click the label, it will trigger the click of the check, which will in turn bubble up to the label, thus firing twice. If you don't want this behaviour you can prevent default perhaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your HTML code

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="copyRec()" id="like" value="val"/>
<label for="like" >Click</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is firing **twice** because `copyRec()` is call on your *label* **and** on your *input* (checkbox).

I would suggest to move `ng-click` to the `input` only:

```
<label for="like">
    <input type="checkbox" id="like" value="val" ng-click="copyRec()"/>
    Click
</label>
```

Comment: Hi that is not working you can check the working code above